# Using dotnet pack creates NUGET with dependencies but without my own code

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a simple .NET Core 3.1 class library that implements some logging functionality inside classes and has a `nlog.config` file. The `.csproj` looks like this

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <NuspecFile>Sima.Logging.nuspec</NuspecFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
      
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

As you can see, my `.csproj` references a `.nuspec` file. I need to do this because I want to include the `nlog.config` as a content file. The `.nuspec` looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Sima.Logging</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
            
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**/nlog.config" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>
            
    <dependencies>
      <group>
        <dependency id="NLog" version="4.7.12" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" version="4.9.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
        
  <files>
    <file src="contentFiles\**" target="contentFiles" />
  </files>
</package>
```

After packaging my library using `dotnet pack`, the nupkg only includes the two dependencies to NLog, but **none of my actual code (in my class) is included in the package**.

[image]

It seems like NuGet doesnt know what to actually build. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating Nuget package (*.nupkg), you must define all files you want to be included in that package. In nuspec config you are missing following:

```xml
<files>
   <file src="bin\Debug\*.dll" target="lib" />
</files>
```

Where `bin\Debug\` is the output path of your build. For further reference please visit [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files).

Comment: I was just going to write the same. Downside is that you now have to manually know which files to include where (gets particularly complicated if your project has multiple target frameworks)